# Cursor moves to end of input when tooltip in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, input-mask

I am trying to build an input field where it accepts time as an input here is my code

```
      <InputMask
          mask="99:99"
          onBlur={handleOnBlur}
          onChange={(e) => {
            const text = e.target.value
            setInputValue(text)
            setValueValid(true)
            const fixedText = text.replace(/:/g, '')
            if (onChange) {
              onChange({
                ...e,
                target: {
                  ...e.target,
                  value: fixedText,
                },
              })
            }
          }}
          //value={inputValue}
          {...rest}
      >
        {(inputProps) => (
          <Tooltip              
              open={!valueValid}
              placement="bottom-start"
              title="Ops Wrong Time Format!"
          >
            <StyledInput
                {...inputProps}
                autoFocus={rest.autoFocus}
                className={rest.className}
                onKeyDown={(e) => {
                  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                    checkTimeFormat(inputValue)
                    if (valueValid) {
                      if (rest.onBlur) rest.onBlur(e)

                      e.target.blur()
                      if (onSubmit) {
                        const fixedText = inputValue.replace(/:/g, '')
                        onSubmit({
                          ...e,
                          target: {
                            ...e.target,
                            value: fixedText,
                          },
                        }, fixedText)
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }}
            />
          </Tooltip>
        )}
      </InputMask>
    )
```

I am trying to use [InputMask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-input-mask) to set the correct format and to make sure only numbers are used as an input. I would like to display a [tooltip](https://material-ui.com/components/tooltips/) if the time is not an acceptable time (eg/ 75:89, 99:78...etc) So everything seems to be working and I am able to see the tooltip if i type in something invalid, however, I am not able to get rid of a strange behavior where the cursor always ends up at the end of the input box after any sort of change... I have searched online for an answer but it seems that nothing was of much help. Note that if I remove the tooltip component wrapping my custom input (StyledInput) then everything turns back to normal (cursor stops where the user is currently modifying).

At first I thought this was a rendering issue so I tried commenting out the hooks

```
setInputValue(text)
setValueValid(true)
```

and even tried to remove the toggle for the tooltip
    open={!valueValid}

but it seems that the tooltip is what's causing the issue... does anyone have any idea how to solve this? Any recommendations or reference to a doc would be of great help!

Here is the sandbox code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-frost-0dy78

Comment: Please create a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: here is the code with the problem 
https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-frost-0dy78

Comment: You setState on any change which causes the input to rerender because it's not a controlled input (read on those!). Consider reacting to the `input` event instead which only triggers when the user is done entering text.

Comment: Looking at the sandbox: You actually don't, material's tooltip does. If you replace the tooltip with a div containing an input things work. Wrap the tooltip in another element and things will work (put it in a div for example)... yuck.

Comment: hmmmm interesting... why does this work? Is it because tooltip rerenders every time something changes in the child, but since we separated it, the change from the user is no longer affecting tooltip because it has a different parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the `Tooltip` around the entire `InputMask` element (rather than around the `input` inside `InputMask`) it works fine. I haven't taken the time to fully understand why the `Tooltip` causes issues in the previous location (which would require digging deeper into the internals of `InputMask` to understand how it manages cursor position), but it isn't surprising to me that it causes issues there.

Below is a modified version of your sandbox:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";
import InputMask from "react-input-mask";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("value");
  const [valueValid, setValueValid] = useState(true);

  const checkTimeFormat = time => {
    const [hour, minute] = time.split(":");
    if (parseInt(hour, 10) > 23 || parseInt(minute, 10) > 59) {
      setValueValid(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Tooltip
      open={!valueValid}
      placement="bottom-start"
      title="Ops Wrong Time Format"
    >
      <InputMask
        mask="99:99"
        //beforeMaskedValueChange={beforeMaskedValueChange}
        onChange={e => {
          const text = e.target.value;
          setInputValue(text);
          setValueValid(true);
          const fixedText = text.replace(/:/g, "");
        }}
        value={inputValue}
        //{...rest}
      >
        {inputProps => (
          <input
            {...inputProps}
            //autoFocus={rest.autoFocus}
            //className={rest.className}
            onSubmit={checkTimeFormat(inputValue)}
            onKeyDown={e => {
              if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                if (valueValid) {
                  console.log("Value is valid");
                }
              }
            }}
          />
        )}
      </InputMask>
    </Tooltip>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit InputMask tooltip]